# Chaining methods failed on coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

server1.coffee

```
http = require 'http'
http.createServer (req, resp) ->
  resp.writeHead 200
  resp.end 'Hi !'
.listen 1337, '127.0.0.1'
```

server2.coffee

```
require 'http'
.createServer (req, resp) ->
  resp.writeHead 200
  resp.end 'Hi !'
.listen 1337, '127.0.0.1'
```

server1.coffee worked but why did server2.coffee get the error below,

```
TypeError: Object http has no method 'createServer'
```

Answer (score 2):

It chains on `'http'`, which is a `string`.

You'd need parentheses around the whole `require 'http'` expression if you want it evaluated properly in chaining syntax.

Comment: Why did chaining `.listen` to `.createServer` work? The callback was passed to `.createServer` without parenthesis.

Comment: I believe this was a bug that got fixed at some point, but I cannot find it now. I believe the fix for this is to indent calls after `requre`. I'll update my answer once I find the relevant issue topic on github. Which version of `cs` do you use?

Comment: Oh, i tested `1.6.3`. i'll update node/coffee to the latest to check again.

Comment: The bug is fixed. `server2.coffee` works now on `1.8.0`. Neither need passing the argument surround parentheses nor the trailing call indent

Comment: That's awesome ;) I suggest watching coffeescript github repo. There's at least a quirk per week

Comment: The price of wiping syntactic noise on `cs` is worthwhile.